# How to Divide Drone Images dataset into Train & Test and Valid Parts for Faster R CNN in Matlab2018b

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network

I have 297 Grayscale images and I would Like Divide Them into 3 parts (train-test and validation).

Ofcourse, I wrote some sample codes for example following codes from [MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/) (Object Detection Using Faster R-CNN Deep Learning)

```
    % Split data into a training and test set.
    idx = floor(0.6 * height(vehicleDataset));
    trainingData = vehicleDataset(1:idx,:);
    testData = vehicleDataset(idx:end,:);
```

But `Matlab 2018a` show the following error

> Error:"Undefined function 'height' for input arguments of type
>   'struct'."

I would like to detect objects in images using "`Faster R CNN`" method and determine their locations in images.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your images are saved in the path "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\myImages"
First, create an [imageDataStore](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.html?s_tid=doc_ta) object to manage a collection of image files.

```
datapath = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\myImages";
imds = imageDatastore(datapath);%You may look at documentation for customizations.
[trainds,testds,valds] = splitEachLabel(imds,.6,.2);%Lets say 60% data for training, 20% for testing and 20% for validation
```

Now you have train data in the variable trainds and test data in the variable testds.
You can retrieve each images using [readimage](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.readimage.html?s_tid=doc_ta), say 5th image from train set as;

```
im = readimage(trainds,5);
```

Comment: hello Thanks a lot - but I wrote Your codes with My Address for My Images but matlab show Error "splitEachLabel requires non-empty Labels property."

Comment: my error fixed with a liitle modify in code. But my New Question is "when click on trainds and testds and valds, these variables are Matlab Sample Images, Not My Images. Is it Correct?

Comment: i studied Matlab help but i dont understand in this code line "imds = imageDatastore(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab'),...
'IncludeSubfolders',true,'FileExtensions','.tif','LabelSource','foldernames')" How to modify These Arguments for Divide Myself IMages and read My Images?

Comment: You did not say About Labeling Images before Divide Train and test. error "splitEachLabel requires non-empty Labels property" exactly Tell I Must Classify Images into 3 parts, Images with Label Home (1) , Images with Label Car (2) and Images with label Tree (3) and Save Column for Labels into Imagedatastore. But I am confused About This Process in Coding?

Comment: Hello, MATLAB allows to use folder names as your image labels. Say you want to label some images as "cars" and "trees"-Then you save them as sub folders of myImages with the folder names as "cars" and "trees". After this use imageDataStore using the syntax imds = imageDatastore(datapath,'IncludeSubfolders',true,'FileExtensions','.tif','LabelSource','foldernames');